# Caching tiles Leaflet 0.7.7

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I've searched here as best as I could, and can't find a direct answer on how I could go about caching the map to speed up loading on zoom. It seems most caching options were introduced in 1.0.0 which I unfortunately cannot use (I can't leverage it at all per Windy guidelines) A live demo of my project can be seen at https://codespent.github.io/dcsg-weather-map and the codebase at https://github.com/CodeSpent/dcsg-weather-map.

I'm restricted to Leaflet 0.7.7 as I'm using the map provided by the [WindyCom API](https://github.com/windycom/API) for weather patterns. Is anyone aware of any references they can point me to that'll help with the zoom loading?

I do believe its the Windy overlay that causes so much of the hangup, but if I can at least better some practices to accommodate that'll suffice for me.

Primary use for this will be a 24/7 screen with reloads on a schedule in our operations center for quick reference.